# Response on Postman works, in pure JS I got: "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, php, json, http-headers, fetch

I have strange situation, while working with my api.
Workflow for now is that I am sending my JSON to my server. My server is changing one information inside that object and response with modified one JSON. Problem is happening when I am trying to accept my server response in javascript.

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Also When I am doing the same request in Postman I am getting my response:

```
{
    "message": {
        "width": 60,
        "height": 60,
        "pixels": [
            "#f0f0f0",
            "#f0f0f0",
            "#f0f0f0",
            "#222888",
            "#f0f0f0",
            "#f0f0f0",
            "#f0f0f0",
            "#f0f0f0",
...
```

I have on idea why my browser act differently.

Here's my JS code on how I sending and retrieving data:

```
startLoad() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/pixel-editor/save', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({picture: this.picture}),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
}
```

Here's my server code in PHP:

```
public function save(Request $request) {
    $data = json_decode($request->post()->get('picture'), true);
    $data['pixels'][3] = "#222888";
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( ['message' => $data] );
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The `<` suggests that the server returned HTML instead of the expected JSON. You need to look at the raw response in the network tool (in the browser's Developer Tools) to see what the full response looked like. Then you might be able to work out how it could have got there